# Can someone merge tags? (and singular versus plural tags)

Tags: support, tagging

Is there someone with the power to merge tags?  If so, I propose merging "macro" and "macros".

More generally, should we prefer singular or plural tags?

Answer (score 6):

Konrad already pointed to the related question in meta.SO.
I guess we should keep it the same way, thus **plurals should be preferred**.

In the beginning it may help to **manually merge the tags, by re-tagging** some of the questions. As long as there are not that many questions and no moderators, this can help to avoid usage of the wrong tag. It is more likely that people will use existing tags, so re-tagging all questions from *macro* to *macros* would lead to higher usage of *macros* and avoids confusion.

As you may have noticed, I have already merged the *macro* and macros *tag*.

Comment: Good point about the retagging, and +1 for doing it rather than just talking about it!

Answer (score 3):

In general, I’m for plurals. This is the established usage on Stack Overflow, compare [Stack Overflow Meta: tag synonym repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms).

Moderators (which will be voted for some time in the public beta, I think?) will have the power to merge tags.

Comment: Also, to whatever extent folk are likely to be swayed by standards, in english-language library practice, plurals are preferred as index terms for non-abstract nouns.  Thus 'macros' rather than 'macro', but 'typesetting' rather than 'typesettings' (!). (disturbingly, I can probably point to an ISO standard for this)