# Merging {localization} into {language}

Tags: discussion, tagging

Sorry for cluttering meta, with a second tag merging proposal today. Should we merge [localization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) into [language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language). Also, should [language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) be renamed to [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages)?

Answer (score 4):

I think not, for two reasons:

1. I think [localisation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localisation) is a more important tag than the number of questions here suggest, and we may be happy in the future that we had the distinuguishing power.
2. The tag has cross-site meaning, unlike [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages): see http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/930/localization

[The consensus](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/can-someone-merge-tags-and-singular-versus-plural-tags) is for plural tags, so we should rename the language tag to languages.

Comment: I guess the cross-site meaning could work with synonym tags as well or at least it could be implemented if generally required. Distinguishing, mentioned by you, is an important point. If you have an idea for their tag wiki text, which helps users to choose the right tag by explaining the differences, it would be great if you would suggest such a text.

Answer (score 3):

Using plural is good. Further I think that merging [localization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) into [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) would be fine as well.

There are just two questions tagged with localization, dealing with Cyrillic.