# Rename {script} to {scripts}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

... and make [script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) a synonym of [scripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripts).

That's following the habit of having tags in the plural form, e.g. [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages), [tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools), [languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages); as per [Our set of tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302/4012) and [Can someone merge tags? (and singular versus plural tags)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/4012).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created the synonym and merged.